# Extracting out the inner text from html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html file, which has the following content:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <pre>I am trying to extract it out</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am tring to get the text from the `pre` block inside the html file, with using `javascript`. I have tried this:

```
let parser = new DOMParser();
const div_new = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
let codes = div_new.body;
let res = codes.pre.text();
```

But it didn't work.
How can I get the text from the pre block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made things complicated,we can use [**querySelector()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to do it,below is reference for you

### ```js
let pre = document.querySelector('pre') 
console.log(pre.innerText)
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <pre>I am trying to extract it out</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

update:
According to OP's comment,below a another choice to do it

```js
let text = 
`
<html>
    <body>
        <pre>I am trying to extract it out</pre>
    </body>
</html>
`

let parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
let pre = doc.querySelector("pre");
console.log(pre.innerText)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought I didn't make myself clear.
The extraction code is in another `html` file (different from the being extracted file), so how can I get the variable `document`, which is mentioned in your code above.